# Unsupported attribute error

Tags: vhdl, vivado, register-transfer-level

I wrote a VHDL function `vectorize()` to convert an array of std_logic_vector (`slv_1d_array_type` type in my code) to std_logic_vector.

Vivado 2018.2 generates this error `[Synth 8-5882] found unsupported attribute ["test_top.vhd":41]` with the example below. I have configured Vivado to use VHDL-2008.

How can I make these `'length` attributes work to avoid passing array size along ?

```
-- Libraries
------------

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Entity
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

entity test_top is
    generic(
        DATA_WIDTH : positive := 32
    );

    port(
        O_DATA    : out std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0)
    );
end entity test_top;

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Architecture
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

architecture rtl of test_top is

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Types definition
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    type slv_1d_array_type is array (natural range <>) of std_logic_vector; -- One-dimensional std_logic_vector array type.

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Functions declaration
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    function vectorize(constant SLV_1D_ARRAY : in slv_1d_array_type) return std_logic_vector is
        variable vector_v : std_logic_vector(SLV_1D_ARRAY'length * SLV_1D_ARRAY'element'length - 1 downto 0);
    begin
        for i in SLV_1D_ARRAY'range loop
            vector_v(SLV_1D_ARRAY'element'length * (i + 1) - 1 downto SLV_1D_ARRAY'element'length * i) := SLV_1D_ARRAY(i);
        end loop;

        return vector_v;
    end function vectorize;

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Signals declaration
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    signal data_r : slv_1d_array_type(0 to DATA_WIDTH / 8 - 1)(7 downto 0) := (others => (others => '0'));

begin

    O_DATA <= vectorize(data_r);

end architecture rtl;
```

Comment: Did you try without the `constant` qualifier?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Same error with or without `constant` qualifier.

Comment: I am not aware that there is a `'element` attribute in VHDL. Try something like `SLV_1D_ARRAY(SLV_1D_ARRAY'low)'length` instead.

Comment: @Juergen Thanks, Vivado accepts your work around.
`'element` is a new attribute of VHDL-2008 that returns the type of the element.

According to Doulos VHDL Golden Reference Guide:
A'ELEMENT Element subtype of A

Comment: There is an `'element` attribute :). But you should try the workaround from @Juergen

Comment: Vivado 2018.1 is totally broken regarding VHDL-2008. Even Vivado 2018.2 has massive problems in handling partially constrained types - you're using one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [UG901](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2018_2/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf) at chapter 6 "*VHDL-2008 Language Support*" there is no mention of `'element` attribute. So it is not officially supported.

This [thread](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/VHDL-2008-ELEMENT-attribute-incorrectly-implemented-by-Vivado/td-p/738004) from Xilinx forums states that it was badly supported and has been removed starting from Vivado 2016.3.

However, the code example above is accepted by ModelSim 10.6c.

The work around provided by @Juergen is working as expected with Vivado 2018.2. Here is an updated version of the example including the work around:

```
-- Libraries
------------

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Entity
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

entity test_top is
    generic(
        DATA_WIDTH : positive := 32
    );

    port(
        O_DATA    : out std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0)
    );
end entity test_top;

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Architecture
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

architecture rtl of test_top is

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Types definition
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    type slv_1d_array_type is array (natural range <>) of std_logic_vector; -- One-dimensional std_logic_vector array type.

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Functions declaration
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    function vectorize(constant SLV_1D_ARRAY : in slv_1d_array_type) return std_logic_vector is
        variable vector_v : std_logic_vector(SLV_1D_ARRAY'length * SLV_1D_ARRAY(SLV_1D_ARRAY'low)'length - 1 downto 0);
    begin
        for i in SLV_1D_ARRAY'range loop
            vector_v(SLV_1D_ARRAY(SLV_1D_ARRAY'low)'length * (i + 1) - 1 downto SLV_1D_ARRAY(SLV_1D_ARRAY'low)'length * i) := SLV_1D_ARRAY(i);
        end loop;

        return vector_v;
    end function vectorize;

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Signals declaration
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    signal data_r : slv_1d_array_type(0 to DATA_WIDTH / 8 - 1)(7 downto 0) := (others => (others => '0'));

begin

    O_DATA <= vectorize(data_r);

end architecture rtl;
```